# checkbox para detereminar se mostra campo ou não

Tags: php, checkbox, if

Estou trabalhando num formulário de cadastro onde aparece o número da certidão de nascimento. Como já devem saber, existe o antigo formato de certidões, com nome do cartório, termo, livro e folha (4 campos), e um formato novo de campo único, com 32 dígitos, onde estão implícitas todas essas informações. Coloquei no meu formulário apenas um campo de texto para colocar esses 32 dígitos da nova certidão, e apenas um checkbox chamado certidão antiga, que quando clicado (checado) irá fazer aparecer os quatro campos para preenchimento com os dados das certidões antigas. Pensei em colocar hidden no campo, e através de  um if, mudar para text quando checado. Mesmo pra essa idéia simples, não consigo achar a sintaxe. Alguém tem uma solução pra esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que gostaria que ficasse da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#potato").on("click", function(event) {
    var check = $("#potato").prop("checked");
    if(check){
        //exibe campos
        $("#idOne").prop("type", "text");
        $("#idTwo").prop("type", "text");
    }
    else{
        //oculta e zera campos
        $("#idOne").prop("type", "hidden").val("");
        $("#idTwo").prop("type", "hidden").val("");
    } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="potato" name="potato" value="potato"><label for="potato">Potato</label><br>
<input type="hidden" value="one" id="idOne">
<input type="hidden" value="two" id="idTwo">
```

Comment: Tá com um erro nessa função, e eu não consigo localizar. Mostra logo na primeira linha.